# Evaluation Error : Need at least one column for 'n_distinct()'

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, count, distinct

I am using the R programming language. I have a data frame (my_file) with 2 columns: my_date (e.g. 2000-01-15, in factor format) and "blood_type" (also in factor format). I am trying to use the dplyr library to produce distinct counts by group (by month).

I figured out how to make non-distinct counts:

```
library(dplyr)

new_file <- my_file %>%
mutate(date = as.Date(my_date)) %>%
group_by(blood_type, month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
summarise(count = n())
```

But this does not work for distinct counts:

```
new_file <- my_file %>%
mutate(date = as.Date(my_date)) %>%
group_by(blood_type, month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
summarise(count = n_distinct())

Evaluation Error : Need at least one column for 'n_distinct()'
```

I tried to explicitly reference the column, but this produces an empty file:

```
new_file <- my_file %>%
mutate(date = as.Date(my_date)) %>%
group_by(blood_type, month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
summarise(count = n_distinct(my_file$blood_type))
```

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count distinct `blood_type` for each month don't include it in `group_by`. Try :

```
library(dplyr)

new_file <- my_file %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(my_date)) %>%
  group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
  summarise(count = n_distinct(blood_type))
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem! If I want to change the group to "week", is this how it should be done?  %>% group_by(month = format(date, "%W-%y")) %>% ?

Comment: If I want to change the group to "day", is this how it should be done? %>% group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%

Comment: For day you can directly use `date` in `group_by`. Week can be calculated in different ways using `%W`, `%V`, `%U` (check `?strptime`) or using `lubridate::weeks`.

Comment: If you have time, can you please take a look at this question (with a bounty)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67764577/r-error-in-xi-xj-non-numeric-argument-to-binary-operator Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my_file)[, .(count = uniqueN(blood_type), 
        .(month = format(as.IDate(my_date), '%Y-%m'))]
```