# (R) Error in Xi - Xj : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, regression, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language. I am trying to recreate the graphs shown in this tutorial over here : https://www.rpubs.com/cboettig/greta-gp

This tutorial shows how to make a special type of regression model for 2 variables. I am able to copy and paste the code from this tutorial and successfully make the desired graphs:

```
#PART 1
#load libraries
library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)

#set seed
set.seed(12345)

#create initial data
x_predict <- seq(-5,5,len=50)
l <- 1

#define functions for evaluating the covariance
SE <- function(Xi,Xj, l) exp(-0.5 * (Xi - Xj) ^ 2 / l ^ 2)
cov <- function(X, Y) outer(X, Y, SE, l)
COV <- cov(x_predict, x_predict)

#sample these functions, place them into a data frame and plot
values <- mvrnorm(200, rep(0, length=length(x_predict)), COV)
dat <- data.frame(x=x_predict, t(values)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-x, names_to = "rep", values_to = "value") %>% 
  mutate(rep = as.numeric(as.factor(rep)))

ggplot(dat,aes(x=x,y=value)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=rep), color =  rgb(0.7, 0.1, 0.4), alpha = 0.4)
```

[image]

```
#PART2

#create new data

obs <- data.frame(x = c(-4, -3, -1,  0,  2),
                  y = c(-2,  0,  1,  2, -1))

#repeat steps from part 1

cov_xx_inv <- solve(cov(obs$x, obs$x))
Ef <- cov(x_predict, obs$x) %*% cov_xx_inv %*% obs$y
Cf <- cov(x_predict, x_predict) - cov(x_predict, obs$x)  %*% cov_xx_inv %*% cov(obs$x, x_predict)

values <- mvrnorm(200, Ef, Cf)

dat <- data.frame(x=x_predict, t(values)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-x, names_to = "rep", values_to = "value") %>% 
  mutate(rep = as.numeric(as.factor(rep)))


gp <- data.frame(x = x_predict, Ef = Ef, sigma = 2*sqrt(diag(Cf)) )

ggplot(dat,aes(x=x,y=value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group=rep), color =  rgb(0.7, 0.1, 0.4), alpha = 0.2) + #REPLICATES
  geom_ribbon(data = gp, 
              aes(x, 
                  y = Ef, 
                  ymin = Ef - sigma, 
                  ymax = Ef + sigma),
              fill="grey", alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(dat = gp, aes(x=x,y=Ef), size=1) + #MEAN
  geom_point(data=obs,aes(x=x,y=y)) +  #OBSERVED DATA
  scale_y_continuous(lim=c(-3,3), name="output, f(x)") +
  xlab("input, x")
```

[image]

Now, I am trying to replicate the above tutorial for a regression model with 3 variables (1 response, 2 predictors). I tried to make the "x_predict" object have two columns instead:

```
x_predict_1 <- seq(-5,5,len=50)
x_predict_2 <- seq(-6,6,len=50)

l <- 1

x_predict <- data.frame(x_predict_1, x_predict_2)


COV <- cov(x_predict, x_predict)
```

But this produces the following error:

```
Error in Xi - Xj : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

This error is preventing me from creating the "values" and the "dat" objects from part 1, and I can not create the desired graphs (e.g. x_predict_1 vs values and x_predict_2 vs values). This is also preventing me from creating the desired graphs in part 2.

Can someone please show me how to fix this problem?
Thanks

Comment: This looks worng `COV <- cov(x_predict, x_predict)`  (those are not the right variable names). But more important I only see two variables.

Comment: I replicated your code at point where you got error COV <- cov(x_predict, x_predict), and it seems to be running ok for me.. Can you check once again ?

Comment: @AnupTirpude : I ran it again and still got the same error. Is it possible that you were running the older definition of "x_predict"? Now, x_predict <- x_predict <- data.frame(x_predict_1, x_predict_2)

Comment: I agree with @AnupTirpude : code running OK.

Comment: What's the question exactly, why you're getting an error, or how to make/fix your chart? I ran just the last block of code and, like others here, don't get an error, so if the question is about the error it doesn't seem to be reproducible. If the question is about the chart, that needs to be clearer. Either way, it would help to scale this back to just the minimal part of [mcve]

Comment: Hi Camille, can you please try to re-run the code from the tutorial if you redefine "x_predict" as:  x_predict_1 <- seq(-5,5,len=50)
x_predict_2 <- seq(-6,6,len=50)

l <- 1

x_predict <- data.frame(x_predict_1, x_predict_2)

Comment: Hi Noob, Any news ? Does my answer resolve your problem ?

Comment: Hi Noob, Sorry but I haven't heard from you.. does the answer is satisfactory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got the problem. First of all below is the way by which we can reproduce the error & the way you have proceed :

```
#PART 1
#load libraries
library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)

#set seed
set.seed(12345)

#create initial data
x_predict <- seq(-5,5,len=50)
l <- 1

#define functions for evaluating the covariance
SE <- function(Xi,Xj, l) exp(-0.5 * (Xi - Xj) ^ 2 / l ^ 2)
cov <- function(X, Y) outer(X, Y, SE, l)
COV <- cov(x_predict, x_predict)

#sample these functions, place them into a data frame and plot
values <- mvrnorm(200, rep(0, length=length(x_predict)), COV)
dat <- data.frame(x=x_predict, t(values)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-x, names_to = "rep", values_to = "value") %>% 
  mutate(rep = as.numeric(as.factor(rep)))

ggplot(dat,aes(x=x,y=value)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=rep), color =  rgb(0.7, 0.1, 0.4), alpha = 0.4) 


x_predict_1 <- seq(-5,5,len=50)
x_predict_2 <- seq(-6,6,len=50)

l <- 1

x_predict <- data.frame(x_predict_1, x_predict_2)

COV <- cov(x_predict, x_predict)
```

At end of this code will end up with an error, same highlighted by Noob

[image]

Here point to note, that the cov function present in base R is redefined and set as below

```
cov <- function(X, Y) outer(X, Y, SE, l)
```

This custom function will only work with vectors/array not with data.frames which is the method used to join the x_predict_1 & x_predict_1 while extending the code.

[image]

If this custom function called on data.frame object it will always result an error as its not build to handle data.frame, it was built only for numeric vectors & arrays

[image]

Now when any new person will try to replicate it from in between, he by default will use 'cov' function from base R. which works on data.frame objects. hence its highly recommended to never re-define existing function in R, it leads to lots of confusion. If we remove the custom 'cov' function and call the cov(x_predict, x_predict) it will work without error which will be called from base R package.

[image]

So to resolve this problem, Noob you just need to use 'c' (combine) instead of 'data.frame' while joining the x_predict_1 & x_predict_2 and your problem will resolved. I am giving the full code I tried with your variables :

```
library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)

#set seed
set.seed(12345)

SE <- function(Xi,Xj, l) exp(-0.5 * (Xi - Xj) ^ 2 / l ^ 2)
cov <- function(X, Y) outer(X, Y, SE, l)

x_predict_1 <- seq(-5,5,len=50)
x_predict_2 <- seq(-6,6,len=50)

l <- 1

x_predict <- c(x_predict_1, x_predict_2)
head(x_predict,5)
COV <- cov(x_predict, x_predict)

values <- mvrnorm(200, rep(0, length=length(x_predict)), COV)
dat <- data.frame(x=x_predict, t(values)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-x, names_to = "rep", values_to = "value") %>% 
  mutate(rep = as.numeric(as.factor(rep)))

ggplot(dat,aes(x=x,y=value)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=rep), color =  rgb(0.7, 0.1, 0.4), alpha = 0.4)
```

The end result will be below graph. I hope this explanation will resolve your problem, if not please let me know.

[image]

here, If you does not want to use 'c' (combine) you can use cbind and create a Matrix. On it you can successfully use your custom function 'cov' it will work. but still when you go further with this approach you will end up another errors. Below is the first one occur due to COV being an array. hence I think or I guess using c (combine) is what you needed.

[image]